# temporarily Stop keydown event fire

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', a);

function a() {
    setTimeout( b, 2000);
}

function b() {
     console.log('b');
}
```

When I press and hold key , *keydown event* will continue

fire. And `function a()` will fire many times.

How to stop fire temporarily, until `function b()` has alreay execute.

It's mean when I hold on key, `function b()` execute every 2 seconds.

Comment: set a flag when the event fires. If the flag is raised, do nothing inside a. Lower the flag inside function b.
Or, Remove the event handler inside function a, reattach the event handler in function b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', fonction () {a()} );

var condition = true;

function a () {
  if (condition) {
    setTimeout(b, 2000);
  }
}

funnction somewhereElse() {
  ...
  condition = false;
  ...
}
```

or

```
var fn = a;
window.addEventListener('keydown', fonction () {fn()} );

function a () {
  setTimeout(b, 2000);
}

funnction somewhereElse() {
  ...
  fn = function(){};
  ...
}
```